# Is the inverse of a function the reflection of the function about the line $y=x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

So, suppose we have$$y = \begin{cases}x & \text{if } x \neq 1\\ 0 & \text{if } x = 1 \end{cases}$$

Will the inverse be the following?$$y= \begin{cases}x & \text{if } x \neq 0\\ 1 & \text{if } x = 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: The easiest way to check is to see if $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$. Does it?

Comment: it gives me 1 when y = 0

Comment: Answer to the question in the title is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. You correctly switched $x$ and $y$ and solved for $y$, and then switched the domain and range.

Answer (score 1):

It’s just a bit more complicated than reflecting the graph about the line $y=x$, because the result may not be the graph of a function any more. Note that if you take your original picture and perform the reflection, there are two points in the new picture with $x$-coordinate $0$, and none with $x$-coordinate $1$.

The elaborate way of describing the situation is: consider a function $f\colon X\to Y$, $X$ being the domain of the function, and $Y$ being the target space. There is a *left* inverse $g\colon Y\to X$ satisfying $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in X$, if and only if the original $f$ was *one-to-one*. And there is a *right* inverse $h\colon Y\to X$ satisfying $f(h(y))=y$ for all $y\in Y$ if and only if $f$ was *onto* $Y$.

Examples with $X=Y=\mathbb R$: the exponential function $\exp(x)=e^x$ is one-to-one but not onto, and has this left inverse $g$: if $t>0$, $g(t)=\ln(t)$, while if $t\le0$, $g(t)=17$. The function $\tan^*$ cooked up from the tangent by setting $\tan^*(x)=\tan(x)$ if $x$ is not an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, and $\tan^*((k+1/2)\pi)=0$ is onto, and has the right inverse $h=\arctan$, the usual inverse tangent function. Notice that $g$ is not a right inverse of the exponential function any more than $h$ is a left inverse of the hoked-up tangent function.

Answer (score 0):

The reflection of a line along the $x$-axis is the inverse IF the inverse of the original function is defined. A function is invertible if it passes the horizontal line test (so that its inverse will pass the vertical line test).